# util.inherits - alternative or workaround

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I am a n00b in node, and find `util.inherits()` very useful, except for the fact that it seems to replace the entire prototype of the original object. For instance:

```
var myClass = function(name){
    this._name = name;  
};

myClass.prototype = {
    (...)
};

util.inherits(myClass, require('events').EventEmitter);
```

seems to erase my original prototype.

That brings me two inconveniences:
1 - I have to declare add properties to my prototype after calling `inherits`,

```
var myClass = function(name){
    this._name = name;  
};

util.inherits(myClass, require('events').EventEmitter);

myClass.prototype.prop1 = function(){...};
myClass.prototype.prop2 = function(){...};
```

and, most important, i think i cannot inherit from two or more different classes.

Can anyone explain to me why this makes sense and what would be a good way to work around this?

Thanks

Comment: util.inherits() is discouraged, use class and extends now: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of node version 5.0.0, [util.inherits](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v5.x/lib/util.js#L782) has been changed to support the behaviour you are looking for using the [setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) method:

FirstBase.js

```
function FirstBase(firstBaseProp){
    this.firstBaseProp = firstBaseProp;
}

FirstBase.prototype.getFirstBaseProp = function(){
    return this.firstBaseProp;
};


module.exports = FirstBase;
```

SecondBase.js

```
var FirstBase = require('./FirstBase.js'),
    util = require('util');

function SecondBase(firstBaseProp, secondBaseProp){
    this.secondBaseProp = secondBaseProp;
    SecondBase.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}

SecondBase.prototype.getSecondBaseProp = function(){
    return this.secondBaseProp;
};

util.inherits(SecondBase, FirstBase);

module.exports = SecondBase;
```

ThirdBase.js

```
var SecondBase = require('./SecondBase.js'),
    util = require('util');

function ThirdBase(firstBaseProp, secondBaseProp, thirdBaseProp){
    this.thirdBaseProp = thirdBaseProp;
    ThirdBase.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}

ThirdBase.prototype.getThirdBase = function(){
    return this.thirdBaseProp;
};

util.inherits(ThirdBase, SecondBase);

module.exports = ThirdBase;
```

instance.js

```
var ThirdBase = require('./ThirdBase.js');

var instance = new ThirdBase('first', 'second', 'third');

// With node < 5.0.0 (Object.create)
console.log(instance.getFirstBaseProp()); // first
console.log(instance.getSecondBaseProp()); // undefined
console.log(instance.getThirdBase()); // undefined

// With node >= 5.0.0 (Object.setPrototypeOf)
console.log(instance.getFirstBaseProp()); // first
console.log(instance.getSecondBaseProp()); // second
console.log(instance.getThirdBase()); // third
```

If you're running an older version of node that supports `setPrototypeOf` (0.12.x does), you can just `export` [util.inherits](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v5.x/lib/util.js#L782) and use it as an internal utility function.

Answer (score 13):

It does *not* make sense that you have to declare your prototype after `util.inherits()`. My guess is `util.inherits` originated as an internal-use-only method, tailored only for the limited internal use-cases it was initially intended for, which at some point got published for general usage. The `util` module is written in pure JS, so it is very easy to implement your own version of `util.inherit` that preserves your prototype. Here's the original `util.inherit` source:

```
exports.inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {
  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: ctor,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
};
```

As for the multiple inheritance, that's going to be a much more difficult problem to tackle, as Javascript's prototype inheritance is not really suited for multiple inheritance at all. Each instance has only a single internal `[[Prototype]]` property, which is used to look up members that are not found in the actual instance. You *could* merge the prototypes of two separate "parent classes" into a single prototype, but you will then lose the inheritance to *their* parents, and you will lose the ability to change the parent prototype and have all children see the change.

Comment: ok, so is there a way to extend an object, similar to jQUery's $.extend?

Comment: Thank you, i will try it when i have the chance

Answer (score 9):

You should first inherit, after the function definition, and then implement your object. Also don't forget to call the superclass constructor in your class's constructor.

```
Function A(y){
  this.y = x;
}

Function B(x,y){
  this.x = x;
  A.call(this,y);
}

util.inherits(B,A);

B.prototype.mythodA = function() {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: You're missing the point here. This is the very thing he's trying to avoid (i.e., typing out B.prototype.xxx every time he wants to add another method to the prototype).

Answer (score 2):

I very much wanted the same thing and was unhappy with extend, so I created this extension to the already useful `util.inherits` method:

```
var util = require('util');

module.exports = {
    inherits : function(sub, sup, proto) {
        util.inherits(sub, sup);
        if (typeof proto !== 'undefined') {
            Object.keys(proto).forEach(function(key) {
                sub.prototype[key] = proto[key];
            });
        }
    }
};
```

I put this in my project's `./util/index.js` and then do this to use it:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('./util');

function Foo() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(Foo, EventEmitter, {
    bar : function(){
        console.log(this instanceof EventEmitter); // true
    }
});
```

Maybe I'll publish this if I find it's robust and useful more and more. I just barely implemented it myself, so I'm giving it a test run.

Let me know what you think!

NOTE: This *does* override methods on either of the classes with the ones defined in the proto hash at the end. Just be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks, seems about right. Push it to github, so the community can try it. I can only try it next week but i will give you feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Inherits-ex](https://github.com/snowyu/inherits-ex.js) library is a browser-friendly enhanced inheritance fully compatible with standard node.js inherits with dynamic inheritance or creation.

- static inheritance
- multi-inheritances(inheritance chain) supports
- **inherits at anytime** -- here is your wanted

  - you can not declare method/property before inherits in the standard way for it will replace the prototype object.
- duplication inheritance check
- Es6 Class supports
- more helper functions

  - `isInheritedFrom(ctor, superCtor|superCtorName)` Check the ctor whether inherited from superCtor
  - `mixin(ctor, superCtor|superCtor[])` Mixin the methods and properties of the SuperCtor: Clone(Copy) all superCtor's properties(methods) to ctor.
  - `isMixinedFrom`
  - `createCtor`
  - `createObject`
  - `createFunction`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a slightly unrelated answer because this is the top result on Google.

If you're running into `Module [MODULE NAME] has been externalized for browser compatibility` errors in vite, e.g., because the library you have uses `util.inherits`, install [`vite-plugin-node-polyfills`](https://github.com/davidmyersdev/vite-plugin-node-polyfills) to fix the error.

See: [Can I silence "Module externalized for browser compatibility" warnings in vite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76886227/can-i-silence-module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility-warnings-in-vite/78124547#78124547)